# python corenlp batch parse

Tags: python, batch-processing, stanford-nlp

I am trying to batch parse document using corenlp python wrapper. batch_parse() gives generator, when I try to  iterate over this generator it gives me following error:

> Invalid maximum heap size: -XmxTrue
>   Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Here is my code :

```html
from corenlp 
import batch_parse 
corenlp_dir = "stanford-corenlp-full-2014-08-27/" 
raw_text_directory = "sample_raw_text/" 
for value in batch_parse(raw_text_directory, corenlp_dir,True): 
  print value
```

When I remove for loop over the generator provided by batch_parse, it don't give this error. So, I guess error is relevant to iteration over generator.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. I missed "raw_output" in parameter passing of batch_parse. So, it should be like this:

```html
for value in batch_parse(raw_text_directory, corenlp_dir,raw_output=True):
 print value
```